# IntelliJ 2017.1.3: Unable to evaluate insert key expression: Cannot find local variable '$this0'

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, responsiveness, console-output

After upgrade to 2017.1.3 the debugger started printing out the lines

> Unable to evaluate insert key expression: Cannot find local variable
>   '$this0'

Everything works ok, but this text clutter the console window making it less responsive

[image]

After the application loads, only these lines remain appearing:

[image]

There are no variables nor watches defined in the debugger window.
How can I make IDEA not displaying these messages so it can be more responsive as before the upgrade?

Version info:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.3
Build #IU-171.4424.56, built on May 12, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.4.0-81-generic
```

Comment: Bug report with the reproducible test case is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA. There was similar issue fixed before: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-14175.

Answer (score 1):

These are warnings from [Async Stacktraces](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/02/intellij-idea-2017-1-eap-extends-debugger-with-async-stacktraces/), please disable them all if you do not need them. Probably some insertion point is not correct.